# Setter method really do in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, release

Here is implement of a setter method:

```
- (void)setCount:(NSNumber *)newCount {
    [newCount retain];
    [_count release];
    // Make the new assignment.
    _count = newCount;
}
```

If `retainCount` of `_count` is <=0, how it can release ?

Comment: how you know retainCount <=0?

Comment: A "getter" method? Do you mean setter?

Comment: @Anoop: Assume that happened

Comment: Why do actual retain counts matter here anyway?  As long as the object `retain`s stuff it holds references to, and issues a `release` for every `retain` it does, its job should be done.  If you do that consistently, then you should never even need to care about the actual retain count.

Comment: You can shorten your setter by calling `_count = [newCount retain];`. Sorry, but my OCD is acting there. Also, I have no idea what you are asking there.

Comment: @JustSid: Your OCD would be causing a memory leak there. In a retained -style ivar setter, the old value does need to be released before the assignment to the new value...

Comment: @JustSid No, that's wrong if the object is set back to itself when it has a reference count of 1. Then it's released, deallocated, and the dangling pointer is retained.

Comment: @H2CO3 I was actually just talking about the last line... I prefer to do something like `[_count autorelease]; _count = [newCount retain];`. No leak, no dangling pointer.

Comment: @JustSid I understood what you were talking about. **Your method is erroneous.**

Comment: @JustSid: Ahh, yes, the `autorelease,retain` is one of 3 general ways to implement a setter; that would work...

Comment: @H2CO3 what's wrong with the `autorelease` and `retain` version? It doesn't leak and the case you mentioned isn't a problem either. It also satisfies my OCD, so win, win, win, no?

Comment: @JustSid No. Consider the following situation. There's an object with a reference count of 1 currently assigned to the property. You re-assign (for whatever reason) the exact same object to the exact same property. Then, your setter releases the object (it doesn't matter whether it's released or autoreleased, its refcount drops to 0), so it's deallocated, then the pointer to the deallocated object is retained (here come nice segfaults, objects mysteriously changing class, etc., etc.)

Comment: @H2CO3: No, `autorelease` does not immediately drop the refcount. It does relinquish ownership, but it does so in such a way that somebody can claim ownership before the object is killed. That's the entire point of `autorelease` — it allows you to relinquish ownership but still allow some code in the current execution chain to keep the object from going away.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, that's not what happens. The `autorelease` won't drop the ref count to 0 immediately, so the object isn't deallocated within the setters scope, so you have time to retain it (bring its retain count to 2) in case it's re-assigning the same object.

Comment: @JustSid Now I see what you're talking about. I thought of something else. You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

The only valid object that can ever have a retain count of 0 is `nil`. And sending any message to `nil` just returns 0 without doing anything else, so that case is covered.

If you mean "how can this work with a deallocated object" — well, it can't. And a deallocated object's retain count isn't really 0, because the object doesn't exist anymore — it's been destroyed and is now just a chunk of memory — so it doesn't have any attributes. Doing anything with a deallocated object is invalid and what will happen is undefined.

Comment: Why others object (except nil) can't have a retainCount of 0 ?

Comment: @DungProton: Cause any other object would be destroyed by that point?

Comment: When `release` is called, it checks the retain count. If the retain count is 1, it destroys the object. So it is not possible to have a live object with a retain count of 0.

Comment: @cHao: When retainCount of an object hit 0, the system will not destroy the memory immediately, and it just mark this memory will be free the memory at some point in the future !

Comment: @DungProton: Your understanding of the Objective-C memory management system is not correct. I mean, it is possible that you could implement your own memory management that way, but that isn't how it works in NSObject and friends.

Comment: @DungProton: Reference counting is not GC.  The object is dead, and the memory freed, immediately.  That it still might look like an object after you've killed it does not mean it is one anymore.

Comment: @RobNapier: Release "Decrements the receiver’s reference count. 
The receiver is sent a dealloc message when its reference count reaches 0." (Apple doc)

Comment: @DungProton: Yes. It is sent `dealloc` when the reference count reaches 0. It isn't marked and freed at some point in the future — it's deallocated right then. And even if that didn't actually happen, those are the semantics of the operation, so any code that depended on an object still being alive after its last release would be incorrect.

Comment: @DungProton: "Sending a message" is essentially calling a function.  "The receiver is sent a dealloc message" means that the destructor is invoked.  Immediately.

Comment: So if I write
`NSNumber* num1;
[num1 release];` what happened then ?

Comment: And I can't understand that someone said `If the retain count is 1, it destroys the object` while Apple docs said that dealloc was invoked when retain count is 0 ! Which right ?

Comment: @DungProton:  It's undefined. You didn't have a valid object reference, so you sent a release message to some unknown piece of memory. It might release the wrong object. It might just blow up. It might not have any visible effect.

Comment: @DungProton: Both.  If the retain count is 1, `release` would make it 0.  Making it 0 makes the object destructible, so `release` destroys the object.

Comment: @DungProton: If the retain count is 1 when you call `release`, then that release makes it 0. You can think of release as being implemented like this: `if (--myRetainCount == 0) [self dealloc];`. (That isn't actually how it's implemented, but that's pretty much how it works.)

Comment: You sure that if retain cout hit 0, memory will be destroyed immediately ? So, the reference which the pointer point to memory will also be destroyed ? The pointer will be destroyed ?

Comment: @DungProton: The pointer won't be destroyed -- just the object it points to.  The pointer still exists, and its value hasn't changed, but it now points at what is more than likely a husk of an object in memory you have given up your rights to.  Anything could happen when you attempt to use it, including a segfault, accidentally using another object that took its place, or even its appearing to work.  Even if it does "work", though, you just got lucky.  Don't use a pointer after you've released it.

Comment: @DungProton: I am quite certain that objects are freed immediately upon receiving their last release under normal circumstances. You can read the source code to the Objective-C runtime and see for yourself. The memory is freed up and can then be used by other allocations. The pointer itself is not destroyed — there is no such thing as "destroying" a pointer value — it is just no longer valid.

Comment: And the pointer still reference to this memory though this memory was freed ?

Comment: Correct. And you will crash if you try to dereference it. Sorry for the confusion over retainCount==1. I just meant that if prior to decrementing it were 1, then it would destroy the object. This is exactly equivalent to destroying it if it is 0 after decrementing.

Comment: @RobNapier: Even "you will crash" is assuming too much.  Pretty much anything could happen, but very little of it would be good in the long run.

Comment: Sometimes it will even look like you can still talk to the object for a short time after releasing it, as the memory is not yet overwritten. This can cause some very sneaky bugs if you don't catch it.

Comment: @cHao is correct. According to spec, the computer is allowed to burn down your house, kidnap your dog, or give you a million dollars. It is "undefined behavior." You should not rely on it crashing.

Comment: If the pointer (ex: pointer p) still reference to this memory though this memory was freed, in some situation (I assumed), this memory was initialized but I didn't init p (one more time), p was still strong reference to this memory. So this memory has 2 strong reference ?

Comment: @DungProton: I can't understand the situation you're talking about. If it has two owning references, it shouldn't have been freed. And `init`ing an already-initialized object isn't something you would ever want to do. Are you maybe confusing manual retain/release with ARC (which automatically retains and releases based on `strong` pointers)?

Comment: @DungProton: Memory doesn't have "references".  It typically doesn't know if anything's still pointing at it.  *Objects* have references, and even those only work properly if you `retain` and `release` correctly.  As for your situation, though...if the memory was reallocated by some other part of the program, you now have two pointers to it.  One just happens to be semantically invalid, though it might even work.

Comment: @DungProton: Thing is, though...in all these scenarios you're coming up with, *your program is broken*.  It has run off the rails, and nothing can be said with any certainty about its status or behavior anymore.

Comment: Pointer p still points to memory segment A.
Because memory segment A was freed,
Pointer p2 (can) also points to memory segment A.
So memory segment A was refered by 2 pointer (2 strong reference) ?

Comment: @DungProton: Two pointers can point to the same memory regardless of whether it was freed. If a piece of memory is freed and two pointers point to it, they are both dangling pointers at that point.

Comment: @DungProton: There is no such thing as a strong reference to something that's not an object.  That's just a pointer.  As far as objects and references go, semantically, `release`ing an object through a pointer to it makes that pointer no longer a reference at all.  It's just a pointer again, til you point it at an object again and `retain` the now-pointed-to object.  (This is not a hard rule, in that it is not really enforced in any way, but your life will be much easier if you think of it that way.)

Comment: @cHao
Ex: `NSObject *obj = [NSObject alloc] init]`
I allocated an memory and obj had a strong reference to this memory.
This right ?

Comment: @DungProton: You could call it that, yes.  I'm not sure "strong reference" has meaning outside of ARC, but the pointer has been counted (ie: the object it points to has a corresponding bump to its retain count), and is keeping the object alive until you release it.  Again, though, the *object* is what you have a reference to.  The memory is owned by the object, and the object's death revokes your rights to that memory til `malloc` or a class's `alloc` method gives you another pointer to it.

Comment: `nil` isn't an object;  there is no valid object that can ever return a `retainCount` of zero.

Comment: @cHao That is incorrect; when you call `[foo release];`, nothing changes about `foo` (beyond the inadvisability of messaging a potentially deallocated object).  In fact, `[foo retain]; [foo retain]; [foo release]; [foo doSomethingElse];` is perfectly valid, if odd, code.

Comment: @bbum: It's perfectly valid only if you ignore the whole semantics of reference counting.  `[foo release];` says "i'm not referring to you anymore", and as i see it, revokes `foo`'s status as a reference to that object.  If you `retain` the object twice, you are claiming a second reference to it...and if you aren't holding another pointer to it somewhere, then whether it's legal or not, that second retain is semantically invalid.

Comment: @chao No, `[foo release]` does **not** say "I'm not referring to the object any more"; it merely decrements the retain count.  If that `release` happens to undo the last `retain` implied by `foo`, then (and only then) does `foo` no longer maintain a valid reference to the object.  And that second retain is actually quite valid and I've seen -- and used -- exactly that pattern in code many times (typically to indicate "I'm holding a reference *here*" *and* "I'm passing a reference to a thread/queue").

Comment: @bbum: Literally, it decrements the retain count.  Semantically, it dissolves a reference.  If you're holding a pointer elsewhere that you want to claim as a reference, then i could almost consider a second retain as valid; though it should have been done through that other pointer, i see the possibility of cases where that's inconvenient.  *Passing* a reference, though?  Sketchy, at best.  Any code that needs one, and doesn't bother to acquire its own, is quite broken.

Comment: @cHao *The only safe way to pass a reference from one thread to another (or from one queue to another) is to **hard retain the object in the sending code**.*   Which is exactly why double-retain is a necessary operation and one reason why a blanket claim that *release dissolves a reference* is incorrect.   `release` sometimes *invalidates* a reference, sure, but not always.

Comment: @bbum: So threading doesn't work with ARC, then?  Without the ability to call that extra `retain`, things must fall to pieces...right?

Comment: @chao Which is exactly why Blocks + GCD or NSThread are the recommended means of implementing concurrency. For GCD, enqueueing a block copies it which causes a retain.  For NSThread, the target object is retained (and that object would typically encapsulate any other needed state by strong reference).  If you go down to, say, pthreads, then -- yes -- you will need to use `CFRetain()` and `CFRelease()` under ARC to safely pass an object from one thread to another (or compile your concurrency code with manual retain-release so you can use `retain/release`, as needed).

Comment: @bbum: So basically, in order to *need* to claim more references than you have pointers, you need to abandon the recommended means of implementing concurrency and step outside the reference-counted world entirely.  Setting aside the questions of what makes that worth doing, and the legitimacy of "passing a reference"...why isn't that reference the sender's holding in the first place keeping the object alive?  If it's being released, why isn't it being passed instead?

Comment: @cHao: The reference the sender is holding *is* keeping it alive — but there's no guarantee that the sender will keep that reference as long as the thread needs it. It's a race condition to assume that some code running in one thread will keep an object alive long enough for code in another thread to complete.

Comment: @cHao Requiring the reference sender to hold a reference would thus require a rendezvous with the receiver such that the receiver can tell the sender that the object has been received.  This would be considerably more fragile due to race conditions and have potentially serious performance overhead vs. the "fire and forget" model that we employ with GCD today.   There are  other reasons why you might end up w/more reference counts than pointers.   If you want to know more, ask a question and I'll answer (we put a lot of thought into this when designing ARC and GCD - I'm happy to share).

Comment: @Chuck: There are pretty significant potential concurrency issues anyway, if the sender's mucking around with that object after it's sent.  If it's going to send a reference, it should probably be sending *its own* reference, and promptly forgetting that object ever existed.

Comment: @cHao: Not necessarily. Some objects are thread-safe, some aren't.

Comment: @cHao requiring such a relationship between sender and receiver incurs a massive amount of fragility and overhead.  Which is why we didn't do it; it is measurable and 20+ years of ObjC concurrency experience confirms that it really is a huge source of bugs.  Beyond that, it renders it impossible to implement "fire and forget" patterns that are common to modern concurrency practices.

Comment: @bbum: So why is Objective-C so fragile?  Even C and C++ don't give me all the trouble you're describing...if anything, i figured it'd be easier with a language that has reference counting baked in to every object.  What makes it so much worse at concurrency?

Comment: @cHao who said it was worse?  This is about correctness.  All the same issues exist in C and C++.   The model that Apple adopted for concurrency is fairly simple while also addressing object ownership without incurring unnecessary sender/receiver dependencies.

Comment: @bbum: Correctness wouldn't require lying to an object about how many references one has to it.  But rewinding a bit to my original point:  Whether one accepts the correctness of double-retaining or not, there is no good reason for double *releasing*, and thus no good reason to consider a reference you've released as anything more than a random pointer to some thing you have just given up your rights to.  `[foo release]; [foo doSomethingElse];` is never semantically correct, whether you've double-retained `foo` or not.

Comment: @cHao No lying about it.  You have invented an additional constraint for `release` that does not exist in the minds of the designers.  `retain`, `retain`, `release`, `doSomething` is both semantically correct and a pattern oft used in concurrent operations outside of GCD and NSThread. Your additional constraint does eliminate some fragility, which is good, but it comes at the cost, as discussed above, of disallowing certain patterns that were very much intended to be used when the system APIs were designed. If you want a proper answer, ask a question. This comment chat is no longer productive.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a class with a `retainCount` instance variable.

```
@implementation MyClass
{
   NSUInteger retainCount;
}

- (id) retain {
    retainCount++;
    return self;
}

- (void) release {
    if (retainCount > 1)
        retainCount--;
    else
        [self dealloc];
}
...
@end
```

Once an object is deallocated, it is dead, gone, done for, etc... Thus, there is no point in ever decrementing the retainCount to 0 because, by definition, the object is going to be deallocated and working with a deallocated object is undefined behavior.

The above is the exact logic of NSObject, but a completely different implementation (you really wouldn't want to see NSObject's *actual* implementation -- it is quite painful).

---

The other source of confusion appears to be what a reference means.

```
 NSObject *foo;
 char *bar;
 NSUInteger baz;
```

For all intents and purposes, the above three variable declarations behave identically [in manual retain/release].

When you say `bar = "Hello, World!";`, you are telling the compiler 'copy the address of the memory that holds the string "Hello, World!" into the memory named `bar`".   Same for `foo`, only you are copying the address of memory that holds an instance of the class `NSObject`.

Now, `baz` may seem different.  But it really isn't except that it holds numbers, not addresses.  But, really, an address is a number!

So, in a setter::

```
- (void)setCount:(NSNumber *)newCount {
    // increment newCount's retain count
    [newCount retain];
    // decrement the _count's retain count (which may cause it to be deallocated or not)
    [_count release];
    // copy the address of the memory that holds the NSNumber instance referenced
    // by `newCount` into the instance variable `_count`.
    _count = newCount;
}
```

There is nothing magical about that assignment [under manual retain release].  It is just copying a number from one variable to the other.  The objects are not impacted at all by this.