# Why does release not set the pointer to nil instead of leaving it pointing to freed memory?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

In the code below, `alert` was allocated and initialized, displayed, and then released. Before and after release, `alert` still points to the same address. Why does the system not set the `alert` pointer to `nil` after `release`?:

```
 -(void) viewDidLoad {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @”Hello”
                       message: @”This is an alert view”
                       delegate: self
                       cancelButtonTitle: @”OK”
                       otherButtonTitles: @”Option 1”, @”Option 2”, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I. Because even if it was appropriate, `release` can't (and doesn't) do anything to the object pointer it is called on, because, as anything in C, it's passed by value. Also, under manual reference counting, pointers are never set implicitly to `nil`, that's a feature of `weak` pointers under ARC.

II. And anyway it would be wrong. The `UIAlertView` class adds itself to some view as a subview when shown, so it gets retained. Therefore its reference count is not zero at the time you're expecting it to be deallocated.

Comment: So, that why alert was still exist after message release ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the object that `alert` points to is still around. It is shown on screen, so it can't be deleted from memory.

Calling `release` only tells the system "I am done with it." It doesn't explicitly remove anything from memory until the system (and any other objects that hold a pointer to that object) is done with it too.

Comment: You meaned release message didn't free memory immediately ?

Comment: No it does not, @DungProton, as was [explained to you at length earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908288/setter-method-really-do-in-obj-c).

Comment: yah, someone said release message free memory immediately but someone said no. That make me confused !!!

Comment: At a high level, the object is no longer valid for you to use when you have released your last claim of ownership over it, @DungProton. That's all you should generally worry about; whether the memory is actually freed or not is irrelevant. At a lower level, when a `release` is sent that causes the object's reference count to transition to 0, the object is destroyed. You can, as Chuck indicated in your other question, look at the runtime library to see exactly what that means.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for a message send like that to change the value of a pointer not local to it. You would have to do an assignment:

```
alert = [alert release];
```

Note that there are [weak pointers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4) available when you compile using ARC, which do indeed use the runtime library to `nil` out your variable when the pointed-to object is destroyed.

Secondly, `release` is not responsible for destroying the object. In many cases, the object is actually still alive after `release` is sent, because it has other owners.

Comment: You mean `__weak UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...` @Yar? Yes, that's legal, although the alert view can be deallocated immediately as far as ARC is concerned.

Comment: Thanks Josh, that's cool, I didn't know that. I'm trying to imagine in what situations, if any, that would be useful.

Comment: You're right, a local variable that auto-`nil`s probably has limited usefulness, @Yar, but if you ever need it, the possibility exists!

Comment: Thanks, I'll be on the lookout for a use-case ;) +1 on this answer, by the way.

Comment: I actually found a use-case today. Within your method, you are using an object (A) and modifying it. A belongs to some other object (B). If A gets dealloced during your use (because B is done with it) you want to be working with `nil` instead of 1) continuing to work with the object (as ARC would do normally) and 2) getting a SIGBART.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer holds "the address of that thing". The `release` goes to "that thing". They're different memory locations.